# Agregar y quitar un elemento?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Tengo una galería de cartas, quiero que al darle click agregue la clase card-view con una rotación de -180deg y ejecute un sonido infoUp.play(); luego al volver a darle click quiero que elimine la clase card-view con una rotación de 180deg y genere otro sonido en este caso infoDown.play();

¿Puedo usar el evento toggle que agrega y quita la clase? pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema de sonido y la rotación. T.T

```js
let selectOfCard = (() => {
 const selectCard = document.getElementById('selectCard').children;
  let rotateCard = document.querySelector('.card-transform');
   for (let i = 0; i < selectCard.length; i++) {
   //Seleciona las cartas
     selectCard[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
       if (num == 0) {
       //Agregar clase, sonido y rotación
        selectCard[i].classList.add('card-view');
        rotateCard.style.transform = 'rotateY(-180deg)';
        infoUp.play();
        
        //Al volver a darle click
        selectCard[i].classList.remove('card-view');
        rotateCard.style.transform = 'rotateY(180deg)';
        infoDown.play();
      }
      
      if(num == 1){
      //Otra carta
      }
      if(num == 2){
      //Otra carta
      }
    });
  }      
});

selectOfCard();
```

Comment: Puedes consultar si el elemento tiene o no la clase `card-view` usando el método [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), que te devuelve un valor booleano, según el cual podrás implementar un condicional para saber si estás añadiendo la clase o quitando la clase (`toggle`) y en base a esto reproducir el sonido adecuado y rotar en el sentido correcto. Saludos

Comment: Gracias, por tu ayuda ya lo resolvi. :')

Answer (score 0):

Agregue un id dentro de selectCard y luego aplique el booleano correspondiente

```js
let selectOfCard = (() => {
 const selectCard = document.getElementById('selectCard').children;
  let rotateCard = document.querySelector('.card-transform');
   for (let i = 0; i < selectCard.length; i++) {
   //Seleciona las cartas
     selectCard[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
       let num = i + 1;
       if (num == 1) {
          //Solución problema
          if(selectCard[i].id === 'active'){
            selectCard[i].id = 'inactive';
            selectCard[i].classList.remove('card-view');
            rotateCard.style.transform = 'rotateY(0deg)';
            infoDown.play();
          } 
          else {
            selectCard[i].id = 'active';
            selectCard[i].classList.add('card-view');
            rotateCard.style.transform = 'rotateY(-180deg)';
            infoUp.play();
          
          }
        }
      
      if(num == 1){
      //Otra carta
      }
      if(num == 2){
      //Otra carta
      }
    });
  }      
});

selectOfCard();
```